# Jupyter installation

Tags: python3

Everytime I try to install jupyter using

> pip3 install jupyter

I get

```
Command /usr/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ig1277kf/pyzmq/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wp_h3lue-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ig1277kf/pyzmq
Storing debug log for failure in /home/tahir-imanov/.pip/pip.log
```

What is the problem?

---

[Here  is full output...](http://txt.do/5l58y)

Comment: What a *off-topic people. It is jupyter not jupiter.  At least google it.

Comment: `Jupyter metapackage for installation and docs.`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Just from browsing the logs, it looks like its missing the `zmq` headers. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev` first?

Actually, it looks like there is a `python3-zmq` package, perhaps installing it first would allow the `pip3 install jupyter` to proceed.